# iOS requirement for live steaming

Tags: ios, rtmp, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm working on the live streaming app like Periscope and doing research on requirement and restriction on iOS.

I found out that Apple only allows `HLS` (Http Live Streaming) for certain conditions. I found such conditions below from apple site.

> If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming.(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW5)

But I'm not sure that `HLS` should be used for both publishing and watching video or only for watching is acceptable? Because i thinking of using `RTMP` for publishing and `HLS` for watching.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an app similar to periscope that is on the app store now and it can use 2Mbps and connects via RTMP protocol to send the data.  So my guess is they no longer enforce it.  I also beleive that at the time that that was written cell service load was possibly to high and they were hoping that HLS would help with that would be my guess.  Now with 4gLTE it can handle the loads a little better.  Again that is just a guess.  My app went up with no problem or mention of that and the review team was more than aware what the app did.